# Python SMTP Send Email and Receive Reply

Tags: python, email, outlook

I know how to send email through Outlook/Gmail using the Python SMTP library. However, I was wondering if it was possible to receive replys from those automated emails sent from Python.

For example, if I sent an automated email from Python (Outlook/Gmail) and I wanted the user to be able to reply "ok" or "quit" to the automated email to either continue the script or kick off another job or something, how would I go about doing that in Python?

Thanks

Comment: You can simply attach 2 links "ok" & "quit" with respective http handlers you created and either redirects or triggers another job

Comment: You could use [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html) to read replies and perform an action.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP is only for sending. To receive (read) emails, you will need to use other protocols, such as POP3, IMAP4, etc.